# Problems with SOAPUI, SpringWS, and Tomcat5.5

Tags: eclipse, spring, tomcat, soap, soapui

Ive been trying to get an example Web Service working using SpringWS and Tomcat5.5

Ive followed examples such as:

1)http://justcompiled.blogspot.com/2010/09/building-...eb-service-with-spring-ws.html

2)http://jamesbnuzzo.wordpress.com/2009/04/14/spring...s-with-jaxb-maven-amp-eclipse/

The latter has an ZIP file which includes the WAR to drop into Tomcat

In both examples the Web Service runs and I can view the WSDL file (eg:http://localhost:8080/eightball/eightball.wsdl)

However, when I startup SOAPUI version 3.6.1, import the WSDL, set the endpoint for example to http://localhost:8080/eightball/eightball, and then try to submit a request to that endpoint, I get the following error.

Fri Nov 05 19:49:05 GMT 2010:INFO:Error getting response for [eightballSoap11.eightBall:Request 1]; java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

With the 1st example I used Eclipse Helios to develop and publish the WebService to Tomcat. Using SOAPUI in this scenario worked and I got the expected Responses back.

When I exported the same project to a WAR file and deployed on Tomcat, I got the SOAPUI connection exception ?!?!

Can anybody please help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem by adding in address="0.0.0.0" to the Connector element in server.xml.

The problem identified also meant that Tomcat could not be reached on address 127.0.0.1:8080 and only by localhost:8080

I think its all down to how Windows was listening on the loopback address for IPv4 and IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

Which SOAP-Version does the Tomcat/SpringWS use, there might be a discrepancy between SOAP 1.0 and 1.2